# Capture path of all accessed nodes in arbitrary Gremlin query

Tags: gremlin

Assuming I have an arbitrary Gremlin query I don't control as input, and a graph database that I run it against, how can I capture the paths of all accessed nodes in the graph, as in, how can I see what parts of the graph are needed by an arbitrary query?

Clarification:
If I run the arbitrary, how can I capture all the accessed data as the query runs, not just the result, but all the data accessed during the query.

Answer (score 0):

Different databases may have explain plan options that give some insight into how a query will run but really the only way to know what a Gremlin query is going to need to visit in the graph is to run it. If you know the schema of the graph you could potentially write some code that analyzes the query to look at the various steps and labels used to make an estimate of what the query will touch but I am not aware of any existing tools that do that.

Comment: It's ok to run the query, but how to capture all the parts of the graph that are needed when I run it?

Comment: Not all Gremlin queries return everything they touch. In some cases adding a `path` step to the query will return everything that was touched but in reality it totally depends on the query. For example if the query is `g.V().out().out()` it will only return the final vertices but `g.V().out().out().path()` will return every vertex that was visited. However for a query like `g.V().out().out().count()` that trick would not work.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, so how to get all the paths of data required for the query?

Comment: Without doing query rewriting there is really no easy way to do it.

Comment: Is there no way to debug a query as it's running to log all accessed nodes?

Comment: How about monkey patching the root, so provide a module that looks like `g` which has a method `V` but method `V` actually calls the real `V` then does some logging, then returns the result of real `V` and for each method (out/count/etc...) - I know it's super ugly, but would it work?

Comment: It's tricker than that as you essentially have to almost subclass every step that may get used in a query. It might be possible to write a TinkerPop Strategy that helps with this but that would also depend on how much control you have over the back end database itself. I wonder if @stephenmallette has any ideas?

Comment: Assuming you can write/use a `TraversalStrategy` in your environment, i guess you could do something like what `profile()` step does which injects `ProfileStep` instances after every actual step and handles the business of collecting data about what was traversed. that's easier than having to subclass all the steps.